# How to deploy my Qt app statically on ubuntu ? It is running on ubuntu 14.04 only

Tags: 14.04, application-development, qt5

I wrote a application with Qt 5.x and the compiled binary is only working

1. on my development machine running 14.04
2. on other machines running 14.04
3. on linux mint 16

I already inserted the CONFIG += static in my pro file .

But when i do `ldd ./my_executable`  it shows a long list of dependent libs from my system .

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63711/building-a-static-version-of-python

Comment: first of all the link is about static building of apps written in python and second thing is that after alot of digging i found that i need to compile QT from source code to build apps statically , my question is that : is it possible to build apps statically with ubuntu sdk ? that i installed on ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: @ktechpit.org No , you have to use command line . you may have to pay for qt commercial license if your app is not open source

Comment: is there any other way so that i can add the libs to the binary ??